# Examples of non fibrations

Tags: category-theory, fibration

What are some illustrating examples of functors $\mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{B}$ which are neither a fibration nor an opfibration?

I've found many positive examples but I'm blanking out on negative ones, and they usually help to build a better intuition.

By fibration here I mean Grothendieck fibration, to be clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the functor $1 \to 2$ (numbers $n$ being seen as final ordinals, say, $\{0 <\ldots < n-1\}$, themselves seen as categories) picking $1$?

Comment: Similarly I've found $2 \to 3$ sending the unique arrow in 2 to the composition in 3.